# How do I make this multi dimential array print the opposite numbers

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So basically this Java program prints

```
43 
39 
71
```

But I have to make it print

```
17 
93 
34
```

Currently I'm having a bit of trouble understanding it, if someone could show me a step by step on how to do this it would help a lot.

```
   int a[][] = {{4,2,7}, {3,9,1}};
   int j,i;
   for(i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++)
   {
       for(j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
       System.out.print(a[j][i]);
       System.out.println();
   }
```

Comment: You mean 43 28 71 and 17 92 34?

Comment: Properly formatted application output

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the order of the loops.

```
int a[][] = {{4,2,7},
            {3,9,1}};
int j,i;
for(i = a[0].length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for(j = a.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        System.out.print(a[j][i]);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You may simply reverse the loop.